# I'm trying to get all data from json variable using javascript and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i'm trying to get all data from JSON variable and console.log them
So basically what i have tried:

```
var users = {
"kyle": {
  age: 16
}
}

users.forEach(user => {
            console.log(user);
});
```

And it throw an error:

> users.forEach is not a function

So any ideas?

Comment: Guess `users` isn't an array (nor is it something else with a `forEach` property)

Comment: It is an JSON variable

Comment: If it's in JSON format, then it's a string. Parse it into an object first with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: I'll try this..

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(users).forEach(user => {
            console.log(user);
});`

Comment: Well.. SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Also i'm using fs

Comment: You need to edit the question and add more details to the code (for example what is the result of `console.log(users)`. All we can tell you from this is that `users` is not an array (maybe it's an object?).

Comment: the variable users must be an array

Comment: Then is there another way to to console.log all data from the JSON variable?

Comment: The edit helps — it's an object. Now, what do you want as a result? You can loop through the properties of this object with `for (user in users) {}`

Answer (score 1):

`users` is not an array, it's an object. So you can't use `forEach` because that's an array method. You can use something like [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Object.entires`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), or [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to loop through an object. Here's an example of the later:

```js
var users = {
  "kyle": {
    age: 16
  }
}

// using for...in
for (user in users){
  console.log("key:",user);
  console.log("value:", users[user])
            
};

// using Object.entries
Object.entries(users).forEach(([key, value])=>{
  console.log(key,":", value)
})
```